# facebook php sdk show img src from array

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get the image src from an array of a Facebook page stream.
I query the table using the facebook php sdk and the following FQL multiquery:

```
$query=array(

"query1"=>"SELECT actor_id, attachment.media, app_data, description, message, permalink, likes.count, created_time, comments.count, action_links, attachment, type FROM stream WHERE source_id = 294546637313646 AND type > 0  limit 50",
"query2"=>"SELECT name, page_id FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT actor_id FROM #query1)");

$response=$facebook->api(array(
'method' => 'fql.multiquery',
'queries' => $query
));

$posts = $response[0]['fql_result_set'];
$author = $response[1]['fql_result_set'];
```

this gives me an array that has this in it:

```
[4] => Array
                    (
                        [actor_id] => 294546637313646
                        [attachment] => Array
                            (
                                [media] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [href] => http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=306133272821649&set=a.306133049488338.53827.294546637313646&type=1&relevant_count=1
                                                [alt] => Test Amp Picture
                                                [type] => photo
                                                [src] => http://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/69480_306133272821649_877073836_s.jpg
                                                [photo] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [aid] => 294546637313646_53827
                                                        [pid] => 294546637313646_561094
                                                        [fbid] => 306133272821649
                                                        [owner] => 294546637313646
                                                        [index] => 1
```

I'm trying to echo the image src, but can't work out how to do so.

I've tried having:
`$pics = $posts[0]['fql_result_set'];`
and then
`echo "<img src={$pics['src']} />";`
but that doesn't work.

Any help please, would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: I see that your array, or at least what you've shown of it, starts with index 4, I'm guessing you will need to access that index: `$posts[4]['attachment']['media'][0]['src']`

Comment: Hi Dale, the array starts at 0, but up until 4, there were no images. I'm looping through using a `for each` so would expect nothing until 4.

Comment: I guess you need to have some exception handling, for that!

Answer (score 0):

untested php code:

```
$query = "SELECT actor_id, attachment.media, app_data, description, message, permalink, likes.count, created_time, comments.count, action_links, attachment, type FROM stream WHERE source_id = 294546637313646 AND type > 0  limit 50";
$response = $facebook->api('/fql?q='.$query);
$posts = $response["data"];

foreach($posts as $post){
   //do stuff

   //check to see if theres an image
     if(isset($post["attachment"]["media"]) and is_array($post["attachment"]["media"])){
          //lets get the first image only!
         $first_pic = $post["attachment"]["media"][0];
         //here's the src of the first picture!
         $src = $first_pic["src"];
         echo "<img src='$src' />";
    }else{
         echo "There is no attached picture!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nearly there, it displays the images on all posts. So for example, 2 facebook posts have images, and 3 do not. When displaying, all posts have the 2 images... It's along the right lines though...

Comment: worked it out, I used the following

`if (isset ($value["attachment"]["media"][0]["src"])){
        echo "<img src='". $value["attachment"]["media"][0]["src"]. "'/>";
      
      }`
and that displays the image without any additional for each loops...

Thanks for you help though Tommy it pointed me in the right direction.